# POST method not allowed in django requests

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-request

I'm trying to call an API using django request.post but getting error 405 'Method Not Allowed (POST)'
urls:
`path('ciu_consume/<str:br>/<int:qty>/', CiuConsumeView.as_view())`
view:

```
class CiuConsumeView(APIView):
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    def get(self, request, br, qty):
        import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
        Response = requests.put('http://inv****.***.***.c***y.in/**/**/***/***/',
                                data={'br': br, 'qty': 1})

        return HttpResponse('Success')
```

In this I'm getting error 404

If instead of 'def get()' I call 'def post' then also I'm getting same error.
Really stuck on this. Any help for this will be helpful.

```
 <form id="form" method="post">{% csrf_token %}

    <table class="table table-hover" id="table_id" class="display display nowrap">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>S. No.</th>
                <th>barcode</th>
                <th>product name</th>
                <th>SKU</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>product ID</th>
                <th>Colour Code</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Mark Loss</th>



            </tr>
        </thead>
            <tbody>
            {% for in_dict in in_dict %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
                    <td>{{ in_dict.br }}</td>
                    <td>{{ in_dict.p_name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ in_dict.sku }}</td>
                    <td>{{ in_dict.qty }}</td>
                    <td>{{ in_dict.p_id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ in_dict.clr_code }}</td>
                    <td>{{ in_dict.status }}</td>
                    <td><input type="button" name="consume" class="btn btn-success" value="consume" onclick="window.location.href='/api/admin-apis/ciu_consume/{{ in_dict.br }}/{{ in_dict.qty }}/';"></td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}


            </tbody>

    </table>
    </form>
```

Comment: how are you submitting data to this view (forms / postman)

Comment: I'm submitting through a form. I'm updating the code. Please check @c.grey

Answer (score -1):

Try adding "https://" in front of the link

So in this case for example if you are hitting the link "http://example.com", try "https://example.com"

Sometimes the request doesn't come through properly to Django because of the upstream server